# How to use sleep in qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator C++. I want to see these two pictures after each other every 3 seconds. But according to my code, it shows just the last image on the screen. Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use QElapsedTimer() and implement a slot which you shall then connect to QElapsedTimer's signal that is emitted after desired time. See Qt help for more information on that.
In the slot, you shall implement your logic of showing the images.

Answer (score 0):

I think that exec(); is the moment where program starts, so you have to change pictures after that. I Would pastle this code inside youre main class, or inside some other function (for example button slot).